# private messaging system for website built-COMPLETE-need advice now

Tags: api, email, messaging, private

I have just had something created similar to the way private messages works on forums, it seems pretty standard on many networking sites. You PM me, then it sends out an automatic email to the other persons regular email address saying you have a PM, log in to your account.

Everything is fine and works but it is sending through my server, im wondering if this will cause me the possibility of getting me blacklisted somehow.

I called companies like icontact and it seems they dont have any sort of API or anything that could work with a site to transfer those emails from your private messaging system, maybe i misunderstood.

I would like to know what is the "correct" way to do it and any companies that provide the solution? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely won't get blacklisted, but your emails are likely to wind up in peoples SPAM folders quite often if the sending server doesn't match the account sent from.

Who's email address are you trying to send from? The users?

Comment: no they set up something in the admin... whateverienter@xyz dot com.(mydomain) Im assuming thats off of my server and nothing to do with someone elses email.